# Determine which View is currently open and get variable from this view

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, background

I am writing a program using Xcode 8.3.3 with Swift 3.1 for iOS 10. This program is a messenger, so it can send and receive messages from other users. This application has several screens (contacts, stats, chats, etc.) and one background thread which receives incoming messages. I need to determine should I show to user a new incoming message or not. I mean if Single Chat Screen with somebody is open I do not need to show user a message, but on any other screen I need to show pop up view. So I need to determine, which View is currently open and receive variable from this view (in my case it is `var chat: Chat!`, it contains chat ID) to determine which chat received a message. Every messenger has similar functionality: WhatsApp, Viber. Does anybody knows how to do this?
I will be thankful for any help or advice.

I do not understand: why this question is going down? Whats wrong with it?

Comment: Are you using websockets?

Comment: No there is 3rd party library.

Comment: Is it a 3rd party websocket library or a chat library?

Comment: In fact, there is no difference, just some thread

Comment: I do not know exactly it is not mine...

Comment: Why did this question received minus?

Answer (score 0):

I think for your case each of your views must have his own chatID and when you receiving some message you have to compare the chatID of your message and your view

Comment: I have a lot views, only one is Single Chat Screen. So when it is open I need to determine his chat id and, if it is equal to message chat id, do not show incoming message. In other case, I need to show.

Comment: As i understand Single Chat Screen is the screen where only you can write message for example save urls or save some important information? But if its not, i dont understand you problem, please be more concret.

Comment: Open your WhatsApp and you will see your chat list. Select one chat and it will pass you to screen with messages. It is single chat screen. If it is opened, and we are chanting, then you will not see pop up message from me. But if you leave this screen, then you will receive all my message in little black box.

Comment: Ok i got it. So you have some tableView or some collectionView with chat lists and they are in some view controller when you receiveing some message and trying to show that pop up check if your self.isViewLoaded && self.view.window != nil,  if it is true, show your pop up ,if it is false store your messages somewhere and show them when viewWillAppear will work

Comment: Yes, I have table view with chats. Each row is a single chat. When user press it, he will be thrown on Single Chat Screen. Each Single Chat Screen has unique chatId. When user receiving a message, I need to find out its chat ID and then decide to show message pop up window or not.

Comment: OK then you have to check
if self.isViewLoaded && self.view.window != nil {
 // show pop up
} else {
 if currentChatID == message.chatID {
//dont show
}
else {
show
}
}
where the currentChatID is the chatID of you selected row

Comment: Where should I do this checking?

Comment: in your ViewController

Comment: And if is not opened? If opened, for example, contacts screen?

Comment: Is your contact screen in another view controller?

Comment: Yes, of course! I have 24 view controllers (screens). And only one of them is Single Chat View. On it I should not show pop up. On others I should.

Comment: Then you dont need any checks for that screens, jsut show your pop up when you receive the message when you in one of that view controllers such as contacts screen

Comment: To do this I need to determine which screen is open. How to do this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152242/discussion-between-arman-galstyan-and-alex).